# Which users can see draft items - content approval(Doc Lib)

Tags: document-library

In the document lib version settings I have selected for only users who can approve items (and the author of the item)

The question is who are the approvers? Is there an approvers group?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Approver Permission level in SharePoint. So those users which have Approver permission level they are able to see Draft items in your case.